# How many changes in Desktop Application After it become Android Application

Tags: android

In MNC company Interview 
this is the qusestion that  How many changes in  Desktop Application After it become  Android Application
Question by company Employer That I have cheply Android mobile Not As much Internal Storage
Internal storage is around 5-10 MB.
And 
Desktop App NFS its space like 1-2 GB & I want to Same this App for Android so what r the changes to make that do this App for Android

In simple words Company want to Desktop App to Android App   so what r the efforts to do this ?

Advanced Thanks for Answer

Pls reply me

Comment: I can't undestand a single woçrd of what you're trying to say. Please reformulate your question, at this moment it's completely ununderstandable.

Comment: .....say, what? This post is nonsensical in its entirety.

Comment: In simple words Company want to Desktop App to Android App   so what r the efforts to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can make out, you want to port a Desktop Application to Android? And this Desktop app takes up 1-2 GB of space.

There is no simple answer to this - it all depends on the application. I can't just tell you what changes to make in order for it to turn into an Android app. This would require a lot of time and effort on your part to go through the whole design process and develop it accordingly.

That's about the best answer I can give you.